# Restrict the number of children in lookup relationship

Tags: lookup, relationships

How do we restrict the number of children to 1 in a lookup relationship?

Comment: check this : - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18097/count-total-child-records-on-parent-object-in-lookup-relationship

Comment: Is there a way to do this without code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would first need a way to know the count of children object your parent object has.  If it were a master-detail relationship, you could use a rollup summary field for this.

You could change your lookup to a master detail, but if you don;t want to do that and keep it as a rollup, you have a few options.

1. Use Rollup helper from the app exchange.  Great tool that allows you
   to simulate rollup summaries on lookup relations.  [Check it out](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI)
2. Try out the declarative rollup summary tool created by Andy Fawcett.
   Its an open source project he did to also allow you to simulate
   rollup summary fields on lookups.  [Check it out](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Declarative_Rollup_Summary_Tool_for_Force.com_Lookup_Relationships)
3. Write something yourself with Triggers or Batch classes (why
   reinvent the wheel?)

Once you have one of these created, then you will have a field on the parent that gives you the count of children.  Then you just need to write a validation rule on the parent that ensures this count field in not greater than 1.

```
Count_Field__c > 1
```